# How should i iterate the same code of a huge request body?

Tags: java, json, rest, junit

Request body (schema draft version 3) contains 100 fields "required:false".
I need a just one testcase which will iterate 100 times and every time it will delete one field which is marked as "required:false" in the schema and send the request and validate the response obtained. 
A sample test method i use is attached, i need to perform variations on the same to achieve the above scenario:

```
    @Test
public void xyz() throws Exception {
    String request = new FileReader().readFile("requests/success_applications.json");
    DocumentContext jsonValues = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(request);
    jsonValues.delete("wer.asd"); 
        given()
            .headers(this.headers.getHeaders())
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(jsonValues.jsonString())
            .log().all()
            .when()
            .post()
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(is(HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
}
```

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on how to ask a good question. What you are asking is too broad.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which line of code you want to change in each iteration? Maybe put a comment on that line in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a loop to iterate over a list of all the fields and then run the body of the test inside that loop for each field.

Once you have that working, you might want to check out JunitParamsRunner if you want to try parameterizing your test.